# Ambiguous definition when using Location API

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am using [Windows Location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
I also using another library, call it "myLibrary".
in myLibrary there is a definition of a class named Location, and it is defined **in a namespace** - myNamespace.

Now when I try to use both definitions, by including "locationApi.h" and also "myLibrary.h" I get a compilation error:

[image: compilation error]

The error is in the file "locationApi" on the definition of the location :

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
class DECLSPEC_UUID("E5B8E079-EE6D-4E33-A438-C87F2E959254")
Location;
#endif
```

I can fix the issue by changing the name of Location in MyLibrary to MyLocation, but I want to understand why is this naming collision happening, because I defined my Location under myNamespace, and I thought that using namespaces should solve this kind of issues.

Comment: do you use `using namespace` for your and the other library?

Comment: I tried everything, with and without using, and to define my new class in myNamespace, but nothing helped.

Comment: Can you provide a short, self-contained example to reproduce the problem?